# How to fix Unresolved external from FILE2.0?

Tags: c++builder, hdf5

I have some HDF5 C code that I am trying to port to C++Builder. I am getting this error at build time:

> [ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'H5check_version' referenced from D:\DELPHITOOLS\PASHDF\C\WIN64\DEBUG\FILE2.O

`H5check_version` is included in `H5public.h` as a macro.

Why does C++Builder not find this?

Answer (score 1):

> `H5check_version` is included in `H5public.h` as a macro.

If that were true, you would not be getting a *linker* error, since macros are handled only during the *preprocessor* stage.

Somewhere in your project, the *compiler* is seeing a declaration of `H5check_version` as a **function**, and your `file2` unit is calling it as a function, but the *linker* can't find the implementation of that function, hence the error.

Your project needs to contain a reference to the appropriate `.lib` file that either implements the actual function (static linking) or tells the linker which DLL the function is exported from (dynamic linking).

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ is case sensitive, so *H5check_version* is different from *H5Check_version*.

AFAIK pascal is not case sensitive at all.

Regards